# When to create Class file and function file during Python programming?

Tags: python

I am beginner to Python. I am getting bit confuse while practicing program. Please help me, how can I determine that I need to create a class file and when I should go for a function file?

Comment: Files aren't "class files" or "function files". Files are modules that can contain zero or more classes *or* functions. If someone told you you can only have one class in a file, then that person is a Java programmer pretending to know Python and you should stop listening to them.

Comment: Pardon me, if my question didn't make you understand. My question is not about Files.
My doubt is, during writing a program, how I can determine whether I need to create a Class or I can go for only a function?

Comment: Classes are generally used to represent `objects` which have both data and functions. On the other hand, functions are generally used to perform a certain task on the data. So, it depends on what your objective is!

Answer (score 2):

Create a function. Functions do specific things, classes are specific things.

1.Classes often have methods, which are functions that are associated with a particular class, and do things associated with the thing that the class is - but if all you want is to do something, a function is all you need.

2.Essentially, a class is a way of grouping functions (as methods) and data (as properties) into a logical unit revolving around a certain kind of thing. If you don't need that grouping, there's no need to make a class.

Answer (score 0):

I would briefly say that:

Classes are the smallest component in Object Oriented Programming, so use them whenever you want to benefit from OOP. I mean inheritance, encapsulation, polymorphism, abstraction...

Functions are helpful when you want to take repetitive code out of the main code and call the same block of code over and over with just changing the input.

- <sub>You should ommit the word "file" from your question. There is no class file or function file. If you have a file that has some Python code inside, it is called a module. Classes and Functions are defined inside the module.</sub>